# How to configure Spring MVC details in applicationcontext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and I need some suggestion. I have a requirement when the application is down I need to display a banner message when user tries to access the application. The appllication is built on Struts 2 and Spring core (not on Spring MVC), but now I want to implement this change using Spring MVC. The logic for fetching data when needed is written, but I need the details on how to configure the details.

I have written the following classes:

1. MaintenanceInterceptor.java
2. MaintenanceInterceptorDAO.java
3. MaintenanceController.java
4. IndexController.java
5. MaintenancePage.jsp

The below configuration I have used to run as a standalone application, but now I need to integrate it with my application. How can do this? Please suggest how to integrate it?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as code... Currently it is completely unreadable.